# Group of words with some length

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have to find all combinations of given words whose length add up to 10. Input will be given like this:

```
words = [
  ["act", "bat", "cat"], 
  ["acta"], 
  [], 
  ["mounts"], 
  ["amounts", "contour"], 
  ["boo", "con", "coo"], 
  ["tots", "tour"], 
  ["mumus"], 
  ["catamounts"]
]
```

I expect the output like this

```
[
  ["act", "boo", "tots"], 
  ["act", "boo", "tour"], 
  ["act", "con", "tots"], 
  ["act", "con", "tour"], 
  ["act", "coo", "tots"], 
  ["act", "coo", "tour"], 
  ["bat", "boo", "tots"], 
  ["bat", "boo", "tour"], 
  ["bat", "con", "tots"], 
  ["bat", "con", "tour"], 
  ["bat", "coo", "tots"], 
  ["bat", "coo", "tour"], 
  ["cat", "boo", "tots"], 
  ["cat", "boo", "tour"], 
  ["cat", "con", "tots"], 
  ["cat", "con", "tour"], 
  ["cat", "coo", "tots"], 
  ["cat", "coo", "tour"], 
  ["act", "amounts"], 
  ["act", "contour"], 
  ["bat", "amounts"], 
  ["bat", "contour"], 
  ["cat", "amounts"], 
  ["cat", "contour"], 
  ["acta", "mounts"], 
  ["catamounts"]
]
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: I solved it but with complexity n^3, can any body do it with O(n)

Comment: @BabluPatel - Post your current code as well.

Comment: Seems like a subset sum problem – it's NP-complete.

Comment: @Bablu, not even close....

Comment: ...@Stefan is right. Fairly large problems are solvable, however.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that I think could be shown to be close to optimal in terms of the number of calculations required. I will first answer the specific question then will present a recursive method that will generate the desired combinations for the general problem.

**Addressing the specific question**

We see there are two arrays of 3-letter words. I'll write that 2-3. Similarly, there are 2-4, 1-5, 1-6, 1-7 and 1-10. We can forget the empty array.

How may ways can the elements sum to 10? Here are the possibilities: 3-3-4, 3-7, 4-6, 1-10.

We simply need to compute combinations for each of these and take their union.

For 3-3-4, we must take one element from each of the following arrays:

```
["act", "bat", "cat"]
["boo", "con", "coo"]
["acta"] | ["tots", "tour"]
  #=> ["acta", "tots", "tour"]
```

We can use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-product) to compute those combinations:

```
["act", "bat", "cat"].product(["boo", "con", "coo"],
  ["acta", "tots", "tour"])
  #=> [["act", "boo", "acta"], ["act", "boo", "tots"],
  #    ["act", "boo", "tour"], ["act", "con", "acta"],
  #    ["act", "con", "tots"], ["act", "con", "tour"],
  #    ["act", "coo", "acta"], ["act", "coo", "tots"],
  #    ["act", "coo", "tour"], ["bat", "boo", "acta"],
  #    ["bat", "boo", "tots"], ["bat", "boo", "tour"],
  #    ["bat", "con", "acta"], ["bat", "con", "tots"],
  #    ["bat", "con", "tour"], ["bat", "coo", "acta"],
  #    ["bat", "coo", "tots"], ["bat", "coo", "tour"],
  #    ["cat", "boo", "acta"], ["cat", "boo", "tots"],
  #    ["cat", "boo", "tour"], ["cat", "con", "acta"],
  #    ["cat", "con", "tots"], ["cat", "con", "tour"],
  #    ["cat", "coo", "acta"], ["cat", "coo", "tots"],
  #    ["cat", "coo", "tour"]]
```

The combinations for 3-7, 4-6 and 1-10 are computed similarly.

**Recursive method for the generalized problem**

```
def doit(words, target)
  recurse(words.reject do |a|
    a.empty? || a.first.size > target 
  end.sort_by { |a| a.first.size }, target)
end

def recurse(sorted, target)
  arr, *rest = sorted
  sz = arr.first.size
  if rest.empty?
    return sz == target ? arr.map { |s| [s] } : []
  end
  return [] if sz > target
  b = recurse(rest, target) # include no element of arr
  return b if sz != target && sz > target/2
  case target <=> sz
  when -1
    b
  when 0
    d = arr.map { |s| [s] }
    b.empty? ? d : b + d
  else # 1
    c = recurse(rest, target-sz)
    if c.empty?
      b
    else
      d = arr.product(c).map { |s,c| [s] + c }
      b.empty? ? d : b + d
    end
  end
end
```

If we execute

```
doit words, 10
```

the solution shown in the previous section is returned, though the elements are in a different order.

**Explanation**

Explaining how recursions work is challenging. The best way, in my opinion, is to insert `puts` statements. That alone, however, is not enough, as it quickly becomes confusing as to which instance of the method is being called. For that reason I suggest indenting results, as I have done below.

```
INDENT = 4

def indent
  @offset += INDENT
  puts
end

def undent
  @offset -= INDENT
  puts
end

def pu(str)
  puts ' '*@offset + str
end
```

```
def doit(words, target)
  @offset = -INDENT #***
  recurse(words.reject do |a|
    a.empty? || a.first.size > target 
  end.sort_by { |a| a.first.size }, target)
end
```

```
def recurse(sorted, target)
  indent           #***
  puts             #***
  pu "sorted=#{sorted}"  #***
  pu "target=#{target}"  #***
  arr, *rest = sorted
  sz = arr.first.size
  pu "arr=#{arr}, rest=#{rest}, sz=#{sz}" #***
  if rest.empty?
    pu "returning (sz==target ? arr.map { |s| [s] } : [])="
    pu "#{(sz==target ? arr.map { |s| [s] } : [])}" #***
    undent #***
    return sz == target ? arr.map { |s| [s] } : []
  end
```

```
  if sz > target  
    pu "returning [] as sz > target=#{sz > target}" #***
    undent #***
    return []
  end
  pu "calling recurse(#{rest}, #{target}) w/o using an element of #{arr}" #***
  b = recurse(rest, target) # include no element of arr
  pu "b=#{b}" #***
  pu "target=#{target}, sz=#{sz}, target-sz=#{target-sz}" #***
  if sz != target && sz > target/2
    pu "returning b as sz != target && sz > target/2" #*** 
    undent  #***
    return b
  end
```

```
  case target <=> sz
  when -1
    pu "  target < sz"  #***
    b
  when 0
    pu "  target == sz" #***
    d = arr.map { |s| [s] }
    b.empty? ? d : b + d
  else # 1
    pu "  target > sz" #***
    pu "calling recurse(#{rest}, #{target-sz}) using an element of #{arr}"  #***
    c = recurse(rest, target-sz)
    pu "c=#{c}" #***
    if c.empty?
      b
    else
      d = arr.product(c).map { |s,c| [s] + c }
      b.empty? ? d : b + d
    end
  end.
  tap do |a|
    pu "returning a=#{a}"  #***
    undent  #***
  end
end
```

Here is a simpler example to use. I will show just a sample of the output. The interested reader may wish to run the code and study the results.

```
test_words = [["ac", "ba"], ["bo"],
              ["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]] 

doit test_words, 8
```

The following is displayed.

```
sorted=[["ac", "ba"], ["bo"], ["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]]
target=8
arr=["ac", "ba"], rest=[["bo"], ["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]], sz=2
calling recurse([["bo"], ["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]], 8) w/o using an element of ["ac", "ba"]


    sorted=[["bo"], ["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]]
    target=8
    arr=["bo"], rest=[["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]], sz=2
    calling recurse([["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]], 8) w/o using an element of ["bo"]
```

```
        ...

       b=[["acta", "tots"], ["acta", "tour"]]
       target=8, sz=2, target-sz=6
       target > sz
       calling recurse([["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]], 6) using an element of ["bo"]


           sorted=[["acta"], ["tots", "tour"]]
           target=6
           arr=["acta"], rest=[["tots", "tour"]], sz=4
           calling recurse([["tots", "tour"]], 6) w/o using an element of ["acta"]

               ...

    c=[["tots"], ["tour"], ["acta"]]
    returning a=[["bo", "tots"], ["bo", "tour"], ["bo", "acta"]]

c=[["bo", "tots"], ["bo", "tour"], ["bo", "acta"]]
returning a=[["acta", "tots"], ["acta", "tour"], ["ac", "bo", "tots"], ["ac", "bo", "tour"], ["ac", "bo", "acta"], ["ba", "bo", "tots"], ["ba", "bo", "tour"], ["ba", "bo", "acta"]]
```

```
  #=> [["acta", "tots"], ["acta", "tour"],
  #    ["ac", "bo", "tots"], ["ac", "bo", "tour"],
  #    ["ac", "bo", "acta"], ["ba", "bo", "tots"],
  #    ["ba", "bo", "tour"], ["ba", "bo", "acta"]]
```